# Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 20.10

I am looking to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to a newer supported version.  I have an old PC that I dusted off and would like to start playing again with Ubuntu again.

I loaded the latest Ubuntu 20 ISO on a DVD and PC boots from disk and I can install the version but it only provides choices for an install that would wipe my data.

There is no choice to upgrade. I was wondering if there is prefered method I can use to upgrade and retain my photos, files and programs that I have installed.

Any advice would help.

I think the current kernel of 12.04 is probably so old that the install process is not allowing the new version to upgrade and to only install.

Comment: Look at the first of the 12 answers of this link. Yours is a very often asked question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: In these case I would make a fresh install; after backing up my important data.

Comment: Thank you all I will try tonight.  Have a great day!